# ASP.NET VB.NET - How to print double quotes in Response.Write?

Tags: asp.net, response, double-quotes

I want an output:

```
<input type="text" onclick="alert('\"')" />
```

But this doesn't work:

```
Response.Write("<input type=""text"" onclick=""alert('\""')"" />")
```

it gives me

```
<input type="text" ')"="" onclick="alert('\">
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This will output what you want:

```
Response.Write("<input type=""text"" onclick=""alert('\x22')"" />")
```

Comment: Hm, this is not exactly what I was looking for, my question is just wrong. I want to output the literal " in my `.aspx` page. I figured it out though, I used `&quot;` instead. But you know, your answer is really solves the question. Thanks!